# How can I choose the result in Randomforest

Tags: random-forest

Currently I am having a big problem with the interpretation of reandom forest results.

I have repeated the random forest 10 times with 10-fold crossvalidation. test set (30%), training set(70%)

However, as the number of samples is small (n<50), the testset results continue to change from accuracy 1 to 0.9.

I have to show the results of the RF for the purpose of publishing the journal.

In general published papers, researchers show specific accuacy, sensitivity, and specificity fixed value as a result.

I know that because of the nature of the random forest, the results are constantly changing.

In summary

My question is that RF shows different results from to run to run despite using the same parameters.

(For example: round1 AUC:0.5 round2 AUC:0.6 round3 AUC:0.7)

In a general paper, researchers show a fixed value for the result of RF (For example: AUC:0.9, sensitivity 99%, specificity 99%)

How can I choose the fixed value from various values

Answer (score 1):

you should take the average of the accuracy of 10 results to give a specific value? 
Which metric(accuracy, specificity,sensitivity,area under ROC curve) you want to show in the results generally depends on the objective of the problem. Sometimes it's better to go for accuracy or Area under the ROC curve and sometimes people would like to have good sensitivity as the criteria.For highly imbalanced data people prefer area under the ROC curve instead of accuracy because getting a high accuracy with imbalanced data will not be a problem.